# Degenerate measure on a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a r.v. taking values in a separable metric space $(E,d).$

Prove that $X$ is degenerate (i.e. $\exists x \in E;P_X=\delta_x$) if and only if $\forall K \in B(E),P_X(K) \in \left\{0;1 \right\}.$

$\implies$ is very easy. Any ideas for the converse?

Comment: Hint: $A \Rightarrow B \quad \iff \quad \neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$

Comment: What does the notation $B(E)$ stand for?

Comment: $B(E)=\sigma(\left\{O, O \ open \ of \ E\right\})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assume that $X$ is also complete.

I will write $P$ for $P_X$. Any Borel probability measure on a complete separable metric space is regular. [Ref.  Convergence of Probability Measures by Billingsley]. Hence there exist a compact set $K$ such that $P(K)>\frac 1  2$ but this implies $P(K)=1$. Hence we may assume now on that $X$ is a  compact metric space.

Now cover $X$ by  a finite union of open balls of radius $1$. The closures of one these is a compact set $K_1$ with measure $1$. (If all these balls have measure $0$ we get $P(K)=0$, a contradiction). Now cover $K_1$ by balls of radius $\frac 1 2$ and so on . We get  a sequence of compact sets $K_n$ with diameters tending to $0$ such that $P(K_n)=1$ for all $n$. By Cantor's Intersection Theorem there is a unique point $x$ in the intersection of these closed balls. It follows that $P(\{x\})=\lim P(K_n)=1$ so $P=\delta_x$.

In if $X$ is not complete we can consider $P$ as a p.m on its completion $Y$. In this case the intersection of the closed balls constructed above cannot be a point outside $X$ because $P(K_n)=1$ for all $n$ and $\cap K_n=\emptyset$ implies that $P(K_n) \to 0$ a contradiction.  Hence completeness is not necessary.

Comment: Are you working under the assumption that he omitted the condition that $X$ is complete?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Thanks for the comment. I didn't notice that OP changed the question.